# maven ignores sourcelevel in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

Okay, I'm pretty sure I'm missing a fundamental point here, but I'm stumped. I'm playing around with maven to get main and test sources to compile at different levels (1.7 & 1.8) - found a lot of posts but haven't gotten it working yet, so back to basics with an empty project.

So first, I want to try off by having maven **not** compile my code by setting the maven-compiler-plugin to source level 1.7 and using 1.8 code (stream).

This is my **test code**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ArrayList<>().stream();
}
```

And this is my **pom.xml**:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

IntellIJ is not having any of it and complains about the source level as expected until I change it. Now, why is it that when running maven from the command line...

```
$ mvn compile
```

or

```
$ mvn install
```

Maven won't complain?

maven version 3.5.0
java version 1.8.0_131

Comment: Try using the -X option when running Maven to see how javac is being called. It may offer hints about what is going on.

Comment: it actually prints source = 1.7 and target = 1.7. Just to be sure I added something that makes the code not compile regardless of source level, which does indeed cause maven to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in the **syntax** that won't work in Java 7. However, the `stream()` method was only introduced in **JDK** 8. This code compiles because you happen to be using JDK 8. If you switch to an older JDK, your code will break.

One way to prevent such potential bugs is to use the [Animal Sniffer Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/animal-sniffer/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/) which allows you to check that you aren't using parts of the JDK that are too new, even when compiling against the aforementioned new JDK:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>animal-sniffer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.15</version>
  <configuration>
    <signature>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.signature</groupId>
      <artifactId>java17</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </signature>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>animal-sniffer</id>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>check</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: of course! that makes sense. If I had just used lambdas instead I would have noticed this right away. Works as intended when I try to use a lambda. Thanks a lot, lesson learnt :)